# How can I use R.layout.emergency_dialer?

Tags: android

I would like to use `"R.layout.emergency_dialer"` from 
 http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/phone/EmergencyDialer.java.html for my project. I basically need 12 keypad button GUI that users can press buttons.

At first, I attempted to copy all the res file including emerge.cy_dialer.xml to eclipse, but R.java was not updated even after manually deleting the R.java file; it did not contain the information of the res file that I copied over.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the built in emergency dialer layout you should probably just write your own XML layout. A 12 button dialer layout should be easy enough to create. Check out Android's layout tutorials if you're uncomfortable layoutting.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Comment: Each of the tutorials on that page has lots of example code as well as walking you through learning the layouts step-by-step.